# <apex:inputText> changes ID and Name

Tags: apex, inputtext

I have a simple form where I need the input box to have the name and id in it.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm

As the docs says, this:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput"/>
```

should output as

```
<input id="theTextInput" type="text" name="theTextInput" />
```

but it doesn't, it outputs as:

```
<input id="j_id0:main-form:theTextInput" type="text" name="j_id0:main-form:theTextInput" />
```

The form is wrapped in:

```
<apex:form id="main-form" styleClass="form-horizontal">
```

Is it possible to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You can find your solution [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190072/how-to-refer-html-element-id-specified-in-visualforce-and-pass-onto-javascript-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have added this recent update as an edit or comment to your question, not as an answer ;)

The gibberish is there to make sure elements are unique. Id field - because Ids should be unique, duh. Name - to make sure submitted form is deserialized properly (if you'd have a table with several items & mass edit capability you'd want to make sure that 7th element's Name field is mapped correctly).

Easiest way around it is to use your own input field instead of `<apex:...>` tag. If that's not an option - you could reference it with jQuery as `$("page\\:block\\:form\\:theInput")` (fully specified path + escaping).

Or use the [ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/): `$("input[id$='theInput']")`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Not to go to far off topic ... do find this method better than using {!$Component.formName.theTextInput} or would you see them as equal? Thanks!

Comment: I don't like $Component, the guy is a bit clunky IMHO. Code that uses it has to sit next to the tag it refers to and I prefer to not sprinkle my JS all over the place but have it in one block on the bottom of the page... But that's a personal pref. really. "Ends-with" might be slow on bigger pages, explicit path will be always fastest but a bit painful if you rearrange the page heavily... Pick your poison ;)

Comment: @eyescream, the note of $Component needing to sit next to the tag (a sibling) is inaccurate. If the $Component reference is used outside of a VF tag hierarchy it simply must be fully qualified in order to retrieve the element id. Using the 1st example: [Best Practices for Accessing Ids](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) script anywhere in the page: `<script> var elId = '{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.theSection.theSectionItem.yourInputFieldIdHere}'; var $myInput = jQuery("[id='" + elId + "']"); </script>` (and is not escaped)

Comment: @MarkPond thx for the tip! I remember playing with it in the past and it was tricky to use so I gave up on $Component. Will retry next time I need JS :) I agree, having the path to be "calculated" server-side will mean less problems like this escaping required by jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I have figure out how to solve for this in my custom jquery error checking.  I just need to reference the name or id as {!$Component.formName.theTextInput}

Note this needs to be run after the field has been rendered to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this post:

http://th3silverlining.com/2011/06/24/salesforce-a-better-way-to-work-with-visualforce-component-ids-and-javascript/

Might provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. That gibberish it adds in there is used by Salesforce, likely for binding, styling and scripting.